# Delete multiple patterns of files using one command (find)

Tags: find, regular-expression, rm

I am trying to `find` and delete files in current directory and subdirectories (recursively) which match different patterns and print the matching files to `stdout` to know which ones are deleted.

For example I want to match all files starting with '&' and all files starting and ending with '$'.
I've tried using:

`find . -type f -name '&*' -or -type f -name '$*$' -exec rm -v {} \;`

but `rm` apply only on the last match ('$*$').
Thus i've tried :

`find . -type f -name '&*' -or -type f -name '$*$' -delete`

But this not only match only the last pattern but it doesn't output the deleted files.
I know I can do this:

``` rm -v ``find -type f -name '&*' -or -type f -name '$*$'`` ```

but I would really like to avoid this kind of approach and do it with `find` command.

Any tips?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is that *exec* only applies to the second pattern, try putting parenthesis around your search conditions, to fix that:

```
find . \( -type f -name '&*' -or -type f -name '$*$' \) -exec rm -v {} \;
```

The thing to note is that this is not a bug, but a feature, so that you can do something like that:

```
find -type f -name '&*' -exec mv '{}' ./backup ';' -or -type f -name '$*$' -exec rm -v '{}' ';'
```

if you need to

Comment: here's where the parenthesis come in handy! This was so simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though [zeppelin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319771/153056) answer is correct, I found also this solution:

find . -type f \( -name '&*' -or -name '$*$' \) -print -delete