# find all files with either extension .ts or .tsx in Unix?

Tags: find

I have a React app where some files are in `.ts` and some are in `.tsx`

Currently in order to update the contents of both .ts and .tsx files, I have to run 2 separate commands:

```
internal-web main % cd src
src main % find . -name '*.tsx' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/SomeThing/SOME_THING/g"
src main % find . -name '*.ts' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/SomeThing/SOME_THING/g"
```

Is there a way I can combine this to one command so that I can update both .ts and .tsx files at once?

Comment: What `find` is this? Are you really on UNIX or do you mean Linux?

Comment: You can combine tests in `find` using `-o` (or `-or` in some implementations) - see for example [Delete multiple patterns of files using one command (find)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319768/delete-multiple-patterns-of-files-using-one-command-find)

Comment: What UNIX is that? That sed usage suggests FreeBSD or derivative (like macos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
find . \( -name '*.tsx' -o -name '*.ts' \) -print0 | 
    xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/SomeThing/SOME_THING/g"
```

Or, simpler and more portable (and avoids a `sed` error if not file is found):

```
find . \( -name '*.tsx' -o -name '*.ts' \) -exec sed -i "" "s/SomeThing/SOME_THING/g" {} +
```

In any case, note that `-i` is not a standard option to `sed`. `sed -i ""` usage suggests the FreeBSD implementation of `sed` (also found on macOS). Most other `sed` implementations either don't support a `-i` or need the `""` to be omitted.

Comment: @stéphane does FreeBSD or more specifically macOS `find` support `-exec ... +`? I know [it's been added to POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), but the [macOS man page](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html) I checked doesn't mention it, so if the OP is using macOS it seems like the small increase in efficiency that `+` provides might not be worth it. Or is the increase more than I think, and/or the `+` certainly supported by macOS?

Comment: it's been in POSIX for decades, feature originally from SysV  in the mid 80s. macOS has been certified as compliant for decades as well. GNU and some BSDs have added them relatively late, but that still was in the 2000s IIRC

Comment: Huh, OK. I guess that's a very old man page then, it just seems odd as macOS itself isn't that old.

Comment: [On FreeBSD specifically, `-exec ... {} +` was added in 2002](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=97736).

Comment: See https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/1/find/ for macos mojave man page.

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks @StéphaneChazelas!

Comment: Note that switching from `;` to `+` is not a *small* increase unless the files are very big or there's only a handful on them. With `-exec ... ';'`, for each file, you're forking a new process, executing `sed` in them which also means loading it, the dynamic linker, all the libraries, do the dynamic linking, do the initialisations (locale, etc)... Using `-exec ... {} +` like with `xargs` also allows the reporting of the failure of any `sed` invocation via the exit status of `find` (or `xargs`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combined filter with `-regex` instead of `-name`. Given the following files

```
src/
src/subdir-2
src/subdir-2/not-interesting.tsn
src/subdir-2/bar.ts
src/subdir-2/bar.tsx
src/subdir-2/not-interesting.not
src/subdir-1
src/subdir-1/not-interesting.tsn
src/subdir-1/foo.tsx
src/subdir-1/foo.ts
src/subdir-1/not-interesting.not
```

you can filter the `.ts` and `.tsx` files with `find src/ -regex '.+\.tsx?$'`

```
src/subdir-2/bar.ts
src/subdir-2/bar.tsx
src/subdir-1/foo.tsx
src/subdir-1/foo.ts
```

Comment: Note that `-regex` is a GNU extension, or at least, not part of POSIX `find` so it might not be available to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to run `find` in this case. If using the `bash`, shell (at least version 4.0, preferably 5.0 or above which has fixed a few bugs in the globstar implementation), you can use globbing instead:

```
sed -i "" "s/SomeThing/SOME_THING/g" ./**/*.ts?(x)
```

This uses the extended matching operators, specifically:

```
'?(PATTERN-LIST)'
     Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns.
```

You'll need to enable globstar first (`shopt -s globstar`) and  `extglob` (`shopt -s extglob`).

Beware it skips hidden files, add `shopt -s dotglob` if you want them to be processed as well as `find` would.

Comment: This would also match e.g `a.txAs`. Did you mean something like `**/*.ts{x,}` instead? Also may fail if there are too many results/ too many too long results.

Comment: @FelixJN No, it shouldn't match files with `.txAs`. I will clarify what it does in the answer.

Comment: I guess it is possible to have it fail if there are too many arguments, but at least in my system, it is set to 2,097,152

Comment: When I run this it shows me an error `sed: 1: "**/*.ts*(x)": invalid command code *`

Comment: @bigpotato Did you enable `globstar` and `extglob`?  Are you using bash? I just tested this command and is working correctly.

Comment: `getconf ARG_MAX` doesn't return the max number of arguments, it's more a limit on the cumulative *size* of the arguments (+ environment variables) which includes the text of those arguments but also the size of the pointers to those arguments (how it's calculated varies significantly between systems and versions thereof). In practice, with a 2MiB ARG_MAX you will likely not be able to pass many more than 100000 file paths.

Comment: Yes, I should have specified I was referring to ARG_MAX. I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter either way, since it is clear OP doesn't have that many typescript files.